# how to make record as a referenceable in datatable lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-design-system

I have the following code, which will return all the opportunities associated with the Contacts, I am getting all the oppty but the I want the returned Oppty name should be clickable and take me to the related oppty. So my question is how can I make this to happen.

Screenshot of current thing:
[image]

#

Lightning CMP:

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId"
                access="global" controller="ContactRolesInfo">
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="ID" />
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
    <aura:attribute name="opportunities" type="List" /> 
    <table class="slds-table slds-table_bordered slds-table_striped slds-table_cell-buffer slds-table_fixed-layout">
        <thead>
            <tr class="slds-text-heading_label">
                <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Opportunity Name">Opportunity Name</div></th>
                <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Account Name">Account Name</div></th>
                <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Stage">Stage</div></th>
                <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Close Date">Close Date</div></th>
                <th scope="col"><div class="slds-truncate" title="Create Contract Contact - Role">Create Contract Contact - Role</div></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <!-- Use the Apex model and controller to fetch server side data -->
            <aura:iteration items="{!v.opportunities}" var="oppty">
                <tr>
                    <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="{!oppty.Name}">{!oppty.Name}</div></td>
                    <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="{!oppty.Account.Name}">{!oppty.Account.Name}</div></td>
                    <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="{!oppty.StageName}">{!oppty.StageName}</div></td>
                    <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="{!oppty.CloseDate}">{!oppty.CloseDate}</div></td>
                    <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="{!oppty.Create_Contract_Contact_Role__c}">{!oppty.Create_Contract_Contact_Role__c}</div></td>
                </tr>
            </aura:iteration>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</aura:component>
```

#

Apex Controller:

```
public class ContactRolesInfo {

    @AuraEnabled
      public static List <Opportunity> getOpportunities(Id conId) {
          system.debug('conId is: '+conId);
        List<Opportunity> opptyList = [SELECT Id, Name, Account.Name, StageName, CloseDate,Create_Contract_Contact_Role__c
                FROM Opportunity Where Contact__r.id =: conId And Create_Contract_Contact_Role__c = true ORDER BY createdDate ASC];
          system.debug('opptyList: '+opptyList);
          return opptyList;
      }

}
```

#

Lightning JS Contoller:

```
({
    doInit: function(component, event, helper) {
        // Fetch the account list from the Apex controller
        helper.getOpportunities(component);
    }
})
```

#

Lightning Helper Controller:

```
({
    // Fetch the oppty from the Apex controller
    getOpportunities: function(component) {
        var action = component.get('c.getOpportunities');

        action.setParams({
           conId : component.get('v.recordId')
        });
        // Set up the callback
        action.setCallback(this, function(actionResult) {

            component.set('v.opportunities', actionResult.getReturnValue());
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    }
})
```

Appreciate you help!!

Comment: Why not use [lightning:datatable](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:datatable/example) - a standard lightning base component that seems to me that can give you all you need?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add an Anchor tag and give the Id of the Opportunity in **href** attrbute like this in your Component :

```
<a href="{!'/'+oppty.Id}" target="_blank">
    <td><div class="slds-truncate" title="{!oppty.Name}">{!oppty.Name}</div></td>
</a>
```

So, in your case the Opportunity name will be hyperlink to the Opportunity.

Comment: Thanks Aditya!
Your solution is worked, but it's opening the record in new tab and in classic mode. My requirement is that the record should open in the lightning mode as same as when we click on the record in the related list in lightning

Comment: Hi Aditya,
I am able to achieve the lightning mode by following, please let me know if I have done it correctly!

<a class="slds-truncate" href="{!'/lightning/r/'+oppty.Id+'/view?0.source=alohaHeader'}" target="">
                            <td><div title="{!oppty.Name}">{!oppty.Name}</div></td>
                        </a>